# JFreeChart import error

Tags: java, jfreechart

Anyone can tell me where can I find the full version of JFreeChart? I downloaded the JCommon and JFreeChart as well (from the sourceforge page), but the JFreeChart contains only the jfreechart-demo.jar, so even if I correctly added the libraries in Eclipse, it doesn't work either...

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unpacked, the required JAR files are in the `lib` directory.

```
$ ls -ln lib
total 5800
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20    45024 Jul 31  2014 hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20   330246 Jul 31  2014 jcommon-1.0.23.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20    13796 Jul 31  2014 jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20    79793 Jul 31  2014 jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20  1570157 Jul 31  2014 jfreechart-1.0.19.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20    50769 Jul 31  2014 jfreesvg-2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20   245039 Jul 31  2014 junit-4.11.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20   445025 Jul 31  2014 orsoncharts-1.4-eval-nofx.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20    72444 Jul 31  2014 orsonpdf-1.6-eval.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20    80054 Jul 31  2014 servlet.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20    17492 Jul 31  2014 swtgraphics2d.jar
```

For example, the following command line runs `TimeSeriesChartDemo1` on Unix; separate class path entries with a semicolon (;) on Windows.

```
$ java -cp .:lib/* org.jfree.chart.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1
```